# Preventing automount in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, fstab, automounting, readonly

How can I tell CentOS 7 not to mount a new IDE drive (new to the system, but with data I want to examine) the first time I plug it in, so that I can do forensic analysis on it knowing I won't have inadvertently let the system write to the drive (e.g. if it decides to run fsck on it, or anything else that might happen from automount.)  I want the straight bits on the IDE to stay exactly as they are.